# what is this parameter in these SqlDataAdapter.Fill and DataSet.Tables

Tags: vb.net, dataset, sqldataadapter

I have this part of code:

```
Dim SqlCommand_customer As New SqlCommand("selectcustomer", conn.con)
SqlCommand_customer.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
Dim da_customer As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim SqlDataAdapter_customer As New SqlDataAdapter(SqlCommand_customer)
Dim ds_customer = New DataSet()
SqlDataAdapter_customer.Fill(ds_customer, "customer")
DataGridView_customer.DataSource = ds_customer.Tables("customer")
```

So I want to know what does `"customer"` stands for in the last two lines
There is nothing named `customer` in the whole file
and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/497b1k4t(v=vs.110).aspx) states that the second parameter in `Fill` must be of type `iDataReader`:

> dataReader
>   Type: System.Data.IDataReader
>   An instance of IDataReader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SqlDataAdapter class derives from [DbDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx) that has a method overload for [Fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4b211hz(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes as second parameter a string.

This string is the name that will be assigned to the table created to store your records or, if you have already tables in the dataset, it is the name of a preexisting table wich will be loaded/refreshed with the records returned by the command.

Of course the syntax in

```
DataGridView_customer.DataSource = ds_customer.Tables("customer")
```

is the way in which you reference this table by its name (that would be the same as `ds_customer.Tables(0)`)

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to the fill command is the name of a table.

You are looking at the wrong reference.  You want the [Fill](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4b211hz(v=vs.110).aspx) command off of the [SQLDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.fill(v=vs.110).aspx).